# MongoDB Remove operation does not remove indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid, pymongo

We have collection with Millions of records with necessary indexes. we have started archiving data and at the same time we remove the data from the production collection.

Now, the indexes are not getting removed with data.

Is there any way to remove indexes along with data. thanks.

For Example,

**Before Backup:**
Number of records - 58002174, 
Index Size - 10.3 GB

**After Backup:**
Number of records - 169376, 
Index Size - 10.3 GB

The Number of records are far less. but, the index size didn't reduce. I need to reduce index size.

Comment: Take a look at dropIndexes() https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/#db.collection.dropIndex

Comment: You can **drop a collection**, and this removes the data and the indexes: [db.collection.drop()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/index.html).

Comment: @PraveenRewar thanks the reply. dropindexes will drop all the indexes. We are not removing the data from the collection completely. we are taking partial backup of the data. in this case, we can not drop the indexes. we need to drop index for the data we removed.

Comment: According to the mongodb documentation, you can use the index specification document while deleting. Please go through the link that I had shared.

Comment: @PraveenRewar I have update the description with an example. I don't want to drop any index. but, size should reduce as I am deleting records from the collection.

Comment: While using db.collection.remove() indexes are not deleted, so if you want to reduce the size, you will have to manually delete the indexes while removing a document.

Comment: @PraveenRewar would you please let me know how to delete index while removing documents from collection.

Comment: @JohnnyHK reindexing worked...after reindexing the size is 26.4 MB. thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnnyHK is there any way to execute reindexing in background?

Comment: @Ravipithadiya See updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild the index to reduce its size after bulk deletions:

[db.collection.reIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/#db.collection.reIndex)

See the warnings in the linked documentation regarding locking and sharding.

Or just drop the index and recreate it. That would allow you to recreate it in the background, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try the compact command: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#dbcmd.compact

It is advertised to "rewrite and defragment all data and indexes in a collection".